# Using FB.api("/me/apprequests") only returns one request. It used to return all. How do you get all with the Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Using

```
FB.api("/me/apprequests", function(response){
});
```

I am only getting one request no matter what. Also, the left sidebar is only ever showing a 1 next to my application.

Example: I have 4 requests currently pending but it only shows a 1 next to the icon in my favorites list and it only loads one request in my "Message Center" within my app.

Anyone else seeing this?

EDIT: I've also confirmed the same happens with the php api.

EDIT#2: I've created a bug if you want to mark repro or subscribe: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/141622979268860?browse=search_4e8a33c8136a20101558833

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that indeed this issue seems to be a bug and a very critical one at that.  Both the Graph API and FQL return a single apprequest which happens to be the latest one for me as well.  And, as jestro describes, Facebook is also displaying a "1" next to the name of the app when there are clearly more than one apprequest for my app.

I stumbled across this problem because I was in the middle of implementing apprequest functions for my game and now it looks like I'll have to set aside implementing the apprequest system for my game while this issue is resolved.  Hopefully someone from Facebook reads this and the problem will get resolved soon.  To that end, I'd like to encourage everyone to confirm this issue for themselves and to subscribe to the bug report jestro submitted so Facebook will pay attention to it.

Thanks all!

btw, if there is a critical bug like this in both Graph API and FQL, does this mean that apprequests for all games are now broken?  If not, what are they doing differently that makes it so they are not affected by this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug that you should log with Facebook.  As a workaround, you should still be able to use an FQL query to get all results:

```
SELECT recipient_uid, request_id, app_id 
FROM apprequest 
WHERE recipient_uid = me() AND app_id = 182197005148613
```

Comment: That also does the same thing.